# Reading resultset from stored procedure using NpgsqlDataReader

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a postgres database with a stored procedure/function. I'm going through the tutorial at http://sqlines.com/postgresql/npgsql_cs_result_sets on reading the results and I'm not getting the same output as described in "Stored Procedure - Working with a Single Result Set in C#".

What am I missing?

Here is what I'm getting.
[image]

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testme() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
            DECLARE
              ref refcursor;
            BEGIN
              OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM achdrow LIMIT 100;
              RETURN ref;
            END;
            $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And my code looks like this:

```
        Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand cmd = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection( "ConnectionString" );
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction tran = null;
        Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader dr;

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "testme";

            cmd.Connection.Open();

            tran = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string x = "";
            if ( dr.HasRows == true )
            {
                while ( dr.Read() )
                    x = dr[0].ToString();
            }

            dr.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            tran.Commit();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<unnamed portal 2> is the automatically name of the cursor, this will help you to understand and solve the problem http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure